# django update time variable in template

Tags: django

What are the options (best way) to update a value of a variable in a template?

template:

```
<div class="time-container">
    {{ time }}
</div>
```

view:

```
def index(request):
    now = datetime.now()
    context = {
        'time': now,
    }
    return render(request, 'times/index.html', context)
```

I would like to show an actual time (django instance synchronized from ntp) updated every seconds. Should I use a websockets?

Comment: An easy enough solution could be just to do Javascript and update the time instead of worrying about it being a variable.  Not sure if that's an option for you or not though.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I would like to show a precise time from backend computer that will be synchronized from ntp.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript. Here's an example using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
<!-- this div will contain time -->
<div class="time-container"></div>

...

<!-- include required js libraries -->
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/moment.js"></script>

<!-- now the actual js code to show time -->
<script>
    function updateTime(){
        $('.time-container').html(moment().format('h:mm:ss'));
    };

    updateTime();

    setInterval(function(){
        updateTime();
    },1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for quickly response, but I would like to show time from backend (ntp sync) not from frontend/client-side.